# EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process lives on after process ended

Tags: node.js, powershell, environment-variables

I need to set an env variable that clears itself out automatically once its process ends. The [process](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.environmentvariabletarget?view=netframework-4.7.2) env type seems a candidate.

However, if I set an env variable in a ps1 script like this

> [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable($key, $value, "Process")

and the script terminates, the variable with name $key is still visible when I

> ls Env:\

I already tried removing the envs in a finally block, but it does not seem to be triggered.

My use case is passing env variables to a node.js process. I do not want to use .env files which are commonly recommended, because that would mean persisting secrets on disk.

Here's my code

```
param(
    [string]$service='serviceName',
    [int]$prod=0
)

try {
    function getSecret {
        param([string]$secretName)
        $secret = (az keyvault secret show -n $secretName --vault-name "VAULT-NAME") | ConvertFrom-Json
        return $secret.value
    }

    function setEnv {
        param([string]$key, [string]$value)
        [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable($key, $value, "Process")
    }

    setEnv -key NAME_1 -value (getSecret -secretName "VALUE_1")
    setEnv -key NAME_2 -value (getSecret -secretName "VALUE_2")
    setEnv -key NAME_3 -value "VALUE_3"

    set-location $PSScriptRoot

    npm run dev
}
catch {}
finally {
    Remove-Item Env:\NAME_*
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should remove the environment variables using the same method as you used for creating them by specifying the target for the environment, in this case `"Process"`.

The way to do that is:

```
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("NAME_1", $null, "Process")
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("NAME_2", $null, "Process")
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("NAME_3", $null, "Process")
```

See [Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.setenvironmentvariable?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks again, by setting them to null in the finally block, I do achieve my desired result. However, this would also be true if the variable scope would have been set to 'user' or 'machine', wouldn't it? Basically, I'm still wondering why the process-scoped variable keeps on living even when the script (and thus the process, to my knowledge, right?) Has completed.